# DBAdvGrid RowHeights - alter all rows except 1

Tags: delphi, tms, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using the following code in the `CustomCellDraw` **event** of `DBAdvGrid`(TMS) to increase row height.

```
procedure TForm1.DBAdvGrid1CustomCellDraw(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  ACol, ARow: Integer; AState: TGridDrawState; ARect: TRect; Printing: Boolean);
begin
DBAdvGrid1.RowHeights[ARow]:=120;
end;
```

How do I make it avoid increasing row 0, which is the 1st row in the Grid, containing column names/headers? - I'd like that row to remain untouched while all the rest should get resized via the above code. Basically it should ignore row index 0 and start from row index 1

Comment: `if ARow > 0 then DBAdvGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] := 120;`? But changing row heights from drawing event smells. Doesn't that control have a kind of `OnMeasureRowHeight` event?

Comment: @Victoria Thanks, it works. Can't seem to find anything related to Measuring rows in the events list, closest I could think of is: `OnRowSize`, `OnRowSizing`, `OnEndRowSize` . Using the code in any of these doesn't work. Mind explaining why is it a problem using the draw event? Meanwhile I'll read up if there is a more proper event for this

Comment: Never worked with this grid, but those sound like they fire when the user resizes or is about to resize a row. My point is that drawing event you chose will be fired by far more times than is needed (not speaking what would happen when the user tried to resize a row because that would in turn trigger that drawing event). If there is no event dedicated for row height measurement, I would consider setting heights right after the grid is filled. But I cannot be more specific.

Comment: @Victoria I see, thanks! I'll have a look through the documentation, maybe I can find something related to this. Thanks for the after grid fill suggestion also!

Comment: You're welcome! I just installed trial and found properties you might be insterested in, `DefaultRowHeight` and `FixedRowHeight`. One is for setting row heights, the other for header height (so in the end you may need no code). Set them in the order I wrote them here and you should get the same result. The event for setting row (or actually cell) size is `OnCustomCellSize`, but I have no idea how it's triggered.

Comment: @Victoria Christ, I haven't even noticed those properties o.O - indeed, it works by setting those, no code needed. Thanks for taking the time and looking into it! Make it an answer if you wish and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBAdvGrid1CustomCellDraw(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; 
  ACol, ARow: Integer; AState: TGridDrawState; ARect: TRect; Printing: Boolean);
begin
  if ARow > 0 then
    DBAdvGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] := 120;
end;
```

But do not modify row heights from a drawing event. Such event is triggered frequently, and is used exclusively for content painting, not for adjusting content size. What's worse, if you e.g. allowed row sizing and the user would try to setup row height, it would in turn trigger that event where you would change the height back, so you'd be fighting with the user.

Content sizing should be done earlier, as [**this example**](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg52.asp) shows in the **OnCustomCellSize** event.

But for your aim I think it's enough to set **DefaultRowHeight** and **FixedRowHeight** properties with no additional code.